# Display Slug instead of Name

Tags: categories, taxonomy

Im trying to display the slug instead of the name of on a product single meta.  This is the code which is displaying the current category name with a link to the category.  Id like to do the same but use the slug as instead :

```
<?php        

global $post, $product;

    $cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );

    ?>
    <div class="product_meta">

        <?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Location:', 'Locations:', $cat_counts, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>

    </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it looks like `product_cat` is a custom taxonomy. `get_the_terms` returns an array you can get the slug from. For instance...

```
$terms_array = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'procuct_cat');
$term_slug = $terms_array['your index']->slug;
```

Comment: Thanks,  could you give an example of where that code should be placed in my example ?  The code is from Woocommerce single product meta

Comment: Sorry. I can't help there. I haven't been working with woocommerce. It just so happens I was working on a custom plugin that needs the above functionality. If I had to guess, you could save the `$term_slug` variable and then echo it out or concatenate it to another string. Sorry I can't be more helpful than that!